# C++ Printing an array containing data structures

Tags: c++, arrays, printing, cout

I'm currently a beginner with using C++ and I am having some trouble trying to figure out how to print an array of data structures. I have been searching around to try and find a solution for this however, I have been unsuccessful. Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int P = 5;
int N = 5;

//Create individual
typedef struct 
{
    int gene[5];    
    int fitness;
} individual;

//Population array contains all individuals
individual population[5];

//Initialize genes and fitness level of each individual in the the 
population
int initializeGenes()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < P; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            population[i].gene[j] = rand() % 2;
        }
        population[i].fitness = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    initializeGenes();

    for (int i = 0; i < P; i++)
    {
        cout << population[i];
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

What I am wanting to do is print the 'population' array and the error i'm getting says 'no operator "<<" matches these operands, operands types are std::ostream << individual" and I do not understand how to fix this.

Any help or a solution would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying cout a struct and in C++ this action is only defined for primitive types (int, char, char*, ...), unless you overload the << operator yourself.

What you probably want is to output the primitive data types contained in the struct.

#### Example

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << population[i].gene[i] << endl;
}
cout << population[i].fitness << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to overload the `operator <<` and use a ostream alongside a struct individual as parameters so that you can call cout directly. Here's a snippet:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const individual& ind)
{
    os << "Gene = ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        os << ind.gene[i] << " ";
    }
    os << "Fitness = " << ind.fitness <<'\n';
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `C++11` way to achieve your goal. As underline by @seccpur, the best way is to overload the `<<` flux operator. I took some liberties and transform your code a little bit by using a `class` rather than a `struct`. It will also show you another use of the `<<` flux operator when playing with classes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

class Individual
{
public:
    Individual() : fitness(0)
    {
        gene.reserve(5);
        std::random_device random_dev;
        std::mt19937  generator(random_dev());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(0, 100);
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            gene.push_back(distr(generator) % 2);
    }

    ~Individual() {};

private:
    std::vector<int> gene;    
    int fitness;

private:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Individual& individual); 
};

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, const Individual& individual)
{
    stream << "Gene = ";
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < individual.gene.size(); ++i)
        stream << individual.gene[i] << " ";
    stream << "Fitness = " << individual.fitness <<'\n';
    return stream;
}

std::vector<Individual> population(5);

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < population.size(); i++)
        std::cout << population[i];

    return 0;
}
```

In the above example, you must absolutely declare the following:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Individual& individual);
```

The operator overload is declared `friend` of the `Individual` `class` in order to access its private members.

Also, take care with the `rand()` function. Use as is, it will always generate the same numbers. You should provide a seed to the number generator. One of its usage can be:

```
srand(time(NULL)); // Needed one time.
rand() % 2;        // Can be used multiple time
```